# how to save all the current models in the scene?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello, I am a new user of gazebo, and I can't find the way to save the world and models into one file or folder, it seems that the save function only save the log file which connected to the model files inside the local gazebo folder, and I cannot find the model if I open that file in others PC

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/17643/how-to-save-all-the-current-models-in-the-scene?/) by [xj yang](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4019/xj-yang/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-10-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

When you click `File -> Save World As`, Gazebo saves the current SDF representation of the world, which includes the SDF description for all entities in the world.

However, models often refer to assets outside of the SDF file, like meshes, textures, plugins, etc. When you open the saved wotld on a different computer, you need to make sure all those resources are available and have the same path. [This](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=components&cat=get_started) tutorial explains these concepts.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-10-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1